# How do I move the Impress Pages widget editor to the middle of my screen?

Tags: impresspages

Anytime I use a widget editor it opens up with only a small portion of the editor showing on the left side or my screen.  I have tried to drag it to the middle with no success.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot that we could clearly understand the issue?